# Place an Electron BrowserView/BrowserWindow inside Atom (Editor)

Tags: node.js, electron, atom-editor

How would I place an `electron` [`BrowserView`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view) or [`BrowserWindow`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) inside `Atom` like [in this package](https://atom.io/packages/atom-browser)?

There are many examples online for `BrowserView` and `BrowserWindow`, but every single one opens a new window (not inside `Atom`).

Most frequently used example:

```
import { remote } from 'electron';
const opts = { width: 800, height: 600 };
const win = new remote.BrowserWindow(opts);
```

After some research I learnt:

1. That instances of `BrowserWindow` can be placed within one another.
2. There is a `parent` option (to be used in `opts` in the code above).
3. There is a [`setBrowserView` function](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetbrowserviewbrowserview-experimental).

But I need the correct compatible `Atom` object to do any of the above, if one exists (Atom's `window` object doesn't work, its very different to a `BrowserView`).

More info:
Most of the packages that achieve this use [WebView](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag), which the latest `electron` doesn't support. Even the docs recommend using a `BrowserWindow` (or iFrame).

This may be impossible, but if anyone has any suggestions or solutions, they will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an answer for you unfortunately, but I seem to have no other means of contacting you, including leaving a comment directly beneath your question.

I am experiencing exactly the same issue as you. Recently I've been looking for an inline web browser inside of Atom, and nearly all of the respective packages do not work. Only today I read about electron's dropped support for webview, which probably explains it.

I can offer two non-optimal workarounds that I've discovered:

- Use an older version of Atom, which is not preferred at all
- Use the one [package](https://atom.io/packages/pane-browser) I found that still works for providing inline web browsers inside of Atom. Unfortunately, it dedicates a pane to the browser, prohibiting the use of tabs.

I am mainly writing this answer so that hopefully you and I can connect in some way over IM or email and try to work on this together.

Otherwise, given that this is not an answer, it can be removed.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for adding some useful info, my apologies that I didn't see the notification until now. I think your info is useful, so I'll upvote it. If you're having the same issue with WebView, please upvote this question so that more people see it. As for connecting, happy to, just not sure how to go about it, can we send DMs on this platform? I think there's a chat somewhere.. I'm currently using an old version of Atom, I'll have a better look at that package too. Thanks for your contribution! Let's figure out how to connect.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! I appreciate it. I actually tried to upvote your question during the week, but was prevented from doing so as I had less than 15 reputation points due to being a newbie. And now I'm at 11! About private messages on here, judging by various questions on Meta Stack Exchange it seems not possible. Hopefully it's acceptable to just put my e-mail here, which is ra6hael@gmail.com. (The '6' is indeed in there.)